# File Changes Not Working in OpenERP

Tags: python, css, xml, ubuntu, odoo

I am new to OpenERP. 
I have successfully installed openerp-7.0 in Ubuntu server(local machine).
I have edited some files in helpdesk module in below path in menu
`Sales => Configuration = > Helpdesk => Categories`.

I have edited helpdesk files in below path

```
opt/openerp/server/openerp/addons/crm_helpdesk/crm_helpdesk_view.xml
```

but my changes are not reflecting in the front-end on the above menu.

so shall i need to do anything for changes reflection in frontend?

I need to customize theme & some other functionality in helpdesk module.

Any help my appreciation.

Thanks All.

Comment: Have try it after restart your server? If you are changing py file then you need to restart server and if you are changing xml file then you need to update that module.

Comment: Yes. i have restarted my server. but there is no luck.. changes are not permitting in front end..

Comment: Hi @Arya can you please point out me to updating the module after which is i have modified in xml file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Arya told, You need to update the crm_helpdesk module. to load the changes.if your modifications comes under `<data noupdate="1">...</data>` then check it in new database or change noupdate="1" to noupdate="0". and update it.After that again change to noupdate="1"